# Mysql error 1066 Not Unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

The code is as follows:

```
Select Branch.BranchName, Sum(Inventory.OnHand) From Inventory, Branch 
Inventory.BranchNum = Branch.BranchNum 
Group By BranchName;
```

I am getting a "Not unique table" for Inventory and I don't understand why. Also, why inventory and not Branch?

Comment: Implicit joins are bad.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WHERE` clause:

```
Select Branch.BranchName, Sum(Inventory.OnHand) 
From Inventory, Branch 
WHERE Inventory.BranchNum = Branch.BranchNum 
Group By BranchName;
```